# Service shown 'Disabled' in service manager

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

Now my program is running as a service and registered in service manager under Windows Server 2008 R2.

When I uninstall my program from 'Programs and Features' in control panel, meanwhile keep the service manager window is opened. After this program is uninstalled totally, My program service shown **Disable** status in service manager. How that happened?

I know if the service manager window is shutdown when I uninstall my program, this issue can NOT be happened, so I guess this is a window service issue. Am I right?

Comment: Does the service magically disappear if you reboot after uninstalling?

Comment: @CoreTech yes, after rebooting the service manager window, my service can disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever Windows is unable to completely uninstall a service, it will be marked as disabled and discarded at the next reboot. I am not sure what can cause uninstallation to go this route, but I have seen it happen when the Event Log Viewer is open. I recommend that you ensure that all applications related to windows services are closed when you uninstall.